# Using NSPredicate on a single object

Tags: cocoa-touch, nspredicate

How can I evaluate an [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/) on a single object?

For example:

```
myLabel.matchesPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "numberOfLines > 2 && enabled == YES"))
```

... should return YES if the numberOfLines is greater than 2 and the label is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C answer; I don't know Swift well enough to get the syntax close to correct:

```
UILabel *matchingLabel = [@[ myLabel ] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate ...]].lastObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(...)
let matchesPredicate = [myLabel].filter{ predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }.count > 0
```

or more simply

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(...)
let matchesPredicate = predicate.evaluateWithObject(myLabel)
```

Notice the square brackets around myLabel to create a single element array that we can then filter based on your predicate. If myLabel doesn't match the conditions, the size of the array after filtering will be zero, one otherwise.

Comment: I specifically need to use an NSPredicate.